# add_custom_target is not always reran

Tags: cmake

This first target always reruns:

```
add_custom_target(testcmake1 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Running testcmake1 step 1")
add_custom_command(TARGET testcmake1 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Running testcmake1 step 2")
```

And output is:

```
1>Running testcmake1 step 1
1>Running testcmake1 step 2
```

However, this target gives the same result when first ran, but then, nothing is output on subsequent builds:

```
add_custom_target(testcmake2)
add_custom_command(TARGET testcmake2 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Running testcmake2 step 1")
add_custom_command(TARGET testcmake2 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Running testcmake2 step 2")
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me, can't reproduce the problem when running `cmake --build bld/ --target testcmake2`.

Comment: I am using CMake 3.13.4 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2017 project using cmake 3.13.2.

Comment: So indeed, running your command line seems to provide the expected results. However, running the build from the IDE directly is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the second case an empty target with no outputs is created. To run it from the Visual Studio 2017 GUI you need to right click on the target and choose project only link target.

In the first case it wasn't an empty target.  To run it from the GUI it was sufficient to choose project only build target.

When you run from the command line it invokes MSBuild.exe directly so it works as expected.

It does expose a bug with `add_custom_target(testcmake2 ALL)` because it is never run when building the `ALL` target.